# MySQL Replication: Waiting to reconnect after a failed registration on master

Tags: mysql, replication

I have two MySQL servers in a master-master setup. The setup is exactly the same (following the process I wrote last time) but is not working as expected.

I am receiving the messages:

`Slave_IO_State: Waiting to reconnect after a failed registration on master`

`Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it`

`Slave_IO_Running: Connecting`

I recreated the replication user multiple times to no avail. If I use another user (in this case, admin, which has all privileges) things work fine.

I can't find any reason that the user name would impact on the connection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you have granted user to replicate slave, but if not please do following....

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'repl'@'%.mydomain.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'slavepass';
mysql> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'%.mydomain.com';
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to confirm that this fix is working on my configuration.